# O Levels 2210 Computer Science Pre-Release: Senior Citizens Trip Organizer

Tags: python, programming-challenge

Can anyone go over the code and suggest any edits and/or efficient solutions?

Attached below are the provided tasks and their solutions. The task is copyright of Cambridge International Examinations.

[image: The given tasks.]

```
#©Nosher Zapoo 2017.
#Task 1 starts here.

number_of_citizens = int(input('Please Enter the number of citizens on the trip: '))

#Validation Check:

if number_of_citizens > 2 and number_of_citizens < 37:
    if number_of_citizens > 24 :
        carer = 3
    else:
        carer = 2
else:
    print('Sorry the range of people is 10 - 36. Please Try again.')
    exit()

#Calculating the cost using economies of scale.

total_people = number_of_citizens + carer
if total_people < 17:
    hire = 150
    cost_meal = 14*total_people
    cost_ticket = 21*total_people
elif total_people < 27:
    hire = 190
    cost_meal = 13.5*total_people
    cost_ticket = 20*total_people

elif total_people < 40:
    hire = 225
    cost_meal = 13*total_people
    cost_ticket = 19*total_people
else:
    exit()

#Working out the total cost
total_cost= hire + cost_meal + cost_ticket
avg_cost= total_cost / number_of_citizens
print('Number of Citizens = ',number_of_citizens)
print ('Total Cost = $', total_cost)
print ('Cost per Person = $', avg_cost)

#Task2 Starts!!!

#Creating Empty Lists to append as arrays.
names = []
amounts = []
total_amount  = 0

#Using an undefined loop
for x in range (0, total_people ):
    name = input('Name: ')
    amount = input ('Amount: ')
    names.append (name)
    amounts.append (amount)
    total_amount = total_amount + int(amount)

#Adding Spare people and their costs
if total_people < 17:
    extra_people = 16 - total_people
elif total_people < 27:
    extra_people = 26 - total_people
elif total_people < 40:
    extra_people = 39 - total_people

extra_cost = extra_people*avg_cost
total_cost = total_cost + extra_cost

if extra_people > 0:
    print ('There are', extra_people, 'seats available. Please enter the name & amount of people joining on extra seats')
    updated_people = total_people + extra_people
    for x in range (total_people, updated_people):
        name = input('Name: ')
        amount = input ('Amount: ')
        names.append (name)
        amounts.append (amount)
        total_amount = total_amount + int(amount)

for x in range (0, updated_people):
    print (names[x])

#Task 3 Starts here.

profit = total_amount - total_cost 
if profit > 0:
    print ('Profit gained $', profit)
elif profit == 0:
    break_even_value = total_cost
    print ('The Outing has broken even as the Total Cost is equal to the Total Amount.')
else:
    print ('The Outing is in loss of $', profit)
```

Comment: About the copyright notice: by posting your code on this site, you're sub-licensing it under CC-by-SA per Stack Exchange's terms of service. Note that you will not be able to delete this post (if it comes to that) after it has upvoted answers.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things to improve:

**Task 1**

- the initial validation check is not correct. You are checking for a minimum number of people to be more than 2, while the error message says the minimum is `10`:

  > Sorry the range of people is 10 - 36. Please Try again.
- I would use an inclusive ranges for readability. Also, you can use the *chained comparison*:

  ```
  if 10 <= number_of_citizens <= 36
  ```
- you can use a short `if/else` form when defining `carer`:

  ```
  carer = 3 if number_of_citizens > 24 else 2
  ```
- to avoid over-nesting things, I would handle the "negative case" first:

  ```
  if not(10 <= number_of_citizens <= 36):
      print('Sorry the range of people is 10 - 36. Please Try again.')
      exit()

  carer = 3 if number_of_citizens > 24 else 2
  ```
- *don't hardcode the coefficient values* for costs and hires, define them as constants, or better in a separate configuration file or module

**Task 2**

Some of the things from the "Task 1" can also be applied here as well.

- when you have a throwaway (not used, but syntactically needed) variable, it is agreed to use [`_` (underscore) variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python)
- looks like you don't have to keep the amounts in a list and can simply calculate the total amount, while only collecting names into a list
- the `range()` starts at 0 by default, you can avoid specifying `0`:

  ```
  for _ in range(total_people):
       # ...
  ```

The definition step then might look like this:

```
names = []
total_amount  = 0

for _ in range(total_people):
    names.append(input('Name: '))
    total_amount += int(input('Amount: '))
```

- when you print out the names, you can loop over the names in a list directly instead of looping over indexes:

  ```
  for name in names:
      print(name)
  ```

**Task 3**

- the `break_even_value` variable is set but never used

There were also some [`PEP8`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) violations in terms of code style, like missing spaces around operators or extra spaces after the function calls. Install a linter like `flake8` or `pylint` to catch this kind of common violations.